# Column wise subtraction in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have a numpy matrix I mXn...

Now,  I want to perform the following operation:

```
J(x, y) = I(x+1, y) - I(x, y)
```

The difference operator is "absolute" difference (ie no negative value in matrix J)

Now, I have a lame way to do this which involves looping but want to avoid that here?

Edit: `The J(x,y) is of size m X (n-1)`

Comment: how do you want to handle the edge?  Where x+1 is out of bounds?

Comment: and did you want row wise or column wise?

Comment: @GarrettR: Good question.. actually diff matrix will have one column less than the original matrix to avoid the (x+1) out of bounds issue..Does that makes sense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you could use `np.diff` for this along with `abs`:

```
>>> mat
array([[0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
>>> abs(np.diff(mat, axis=0))
array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1],
       [1, 1, 1, 1, 1]])
```

I'm not sure that there is any real advantage here over the slicing solution posted earlier -- Just when I think about taking element - to - element differences in a numpy array, I naturally think of `np.diff` . . .

**EDIT**

It looks like the slicing solution is significantly faster:

```
>>> timeit.timeit('abs(np.diff(mat, axis=0))', 'from __main__ import np, mat')
3.239274024963379
>>> timeit.timeit('abs(mat[1:,:] - mat[:-1,:])', 'from __main__ import np, mat')
1.287804126739502
```

Looking at the code, it appears that numpy is just constructing those slices under the hood and doing the subtraction in the same way.  For larger arrays (where the subtraction time starts to become comparable to the slice computation, these timings would get closer together), but `np.diff` will always be slower.

Answer (score 2):

How about with slicing like this?

```
# row 1 is all zeros, row 2 is all 1, row 3 all 0s ...
# 10 x 5 matrix
mat = np.array( [ [j%2 for k in range(5)] for j in range(10)])
diff =  np.abs(mat[1:,:] - mat[:-1,:])
print diff.shape # 9 x 5 
print diff  #all ones (no negative one values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe something like this?

```
import numpy as np

I = np.random.randint(0, 10, (4, 6) )
J = np.abs( np.roll(I,-1, axis=0) - I )
```

**Edit:**

The solution above is assuming periodic boundaries in x. You can drop the last row by using

```
J = np.abs( np.roll(I,-1, axis=0) - I )[:-1, :]
```

instead.